# How does reduplication change the meaning of adjectives?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference in meaning of:

它的眼睛大大的。
它的眼睛很大。

and

他有大大的眼睛。
他有大眼睛。

And more generally, when might someone use reduplication for adjectives?

Comment: In English don't you find -- "You have a long, long way to go in mastering the Chinese language"?

Answer (score 4):

Reduplication of adjective put emphasis on it

Same as English: "big" in "He has big big eyes" is more emphasized than the simple "big" in "He has big eyes"

他有**大大的**眼睛 = he has **very big** eyes

它的眼睛**大大的** = his eyes are **very big**

Notice, not all adjective can be reduplicated, for example we do not reduplicate 巨 because 巨 is already a higher superlative of 大

Also, we don't reduplicated adjectives that are made up of two same characters, For example, 茫茫 is a compound word, not a reduplication of 茫; 忽忽 is a compound word, not a reduplication of 忽

Answer (score 4):

Both 它的眼睛大大的 and 它的眼睛很大 means the same.

However, 它的眼睛大大的 sounds **cutie, animating, or vivid**(maybe also **girlish**). 它的眼睛很大 only addresses the fact and doesn't have that effect.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common to use repeated adjectives in song lyrics, to sound more rhythmic and make the lyrics "fit" the poetic structure.  For example, in the song [雪莲](https://music.163.com/#/song?id=238073):

> **蓝蓝**的天空下青草荡漾
>   **红红**的太阳映红了脸庞

We do this in English too, e.g., [Red Red Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Red_Wine).

Answer (score 0):

A.she has a big eye

B.she has a big big eye

so, what's the different? it's the same

in real life you will say A.

but when you writing a story、a novel …. maybe you will use B. to describe something more detail, or make it more emotional