# How "Noun + Adj + Adj + 的" (reduplication of adjectives) is grammatically equivalent to "Noun + (Adv of degree) + Adj"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

This question is motivated from [Why 的 in reduplication of adjectives "Noun + Adj + Adj + 的"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39997/25265). In the answers, it was argued that the *reduplication of adjectives* structure:

1. > `Noun + Adj + Adj + 的`
   >
   > Ex: 他的儿子高高的。

is indeed a *topic - comment structure*:

> `Noun - Adj + Adj + 的`
>
> Ex: 他的儿子 - 高高的。

with a meaning (approximately) equal to:

2. > `Noun + (Adv of degree) + Adj`
   >
   > Ex: 他的儿子很高。
   >
   > Ex: *His son is tall.*

From the previous post, @dan:

> There is no grammar difference between 你的脸很红 [structure 2.] and 你的脸红红的 [structure 1.]. 红红的 acts the same as 很红.

**I don't understand how 1. and 2. are *grammatically* equivalent**. I believe:

- 2. is a *complete sentence*: the Noun (他的儿子) is the subject, the (Adv of degree) + Adj (很高) is the predicate and the Adj (高), the adjectival verb.
- 1. is only a *noun phrase*, without Verb and Predicate. We can see it because the topic - comment structure makes it equivalent to:

  > `Adj + Adj + 的 + Noun`
  >
  > Ex: 他的高高的儿子。

**Where I am wrong in 1.? How can `Adj + Adj + 的` work as a predicate with a verb?**

---

A few **examples** of the **grammatical equivalence** of both structures:

> 这只小猫毛长长的，白白的，非常漂亮。
>
> The hair of this small cat is long, white and extremely pretty.

Here, 长长的 and 白白的 are grammatically equivalent to 非常漂亮.

> 这个孩子的眼睛大大的，和她的妈妈一样。
>
> This kid's eyes are big, just like his mother.

Here, 这个孩子的眼睛大大的 is translated to the complete sentence *This kid's eyes are big*.

Comment: a "topic - comment structure" is not a noun phrase.

Comment: Who do you think"…the topic - comment structure makes it equivalent to:

Adj + Adj + 的 + Noun

"? I don't see any approach to think 他的儿子高高的==他的高高的儿子.  The former is a complete sentence and the latter is a noun phrase, not a sentence.  Why do you think they are the same?

Comment: @Puco4 Yes, but my question is why you think 他的高高的儿子 is a complete sentence? Your this statement is very confusing "is only a noun phrase, without Verb and Predicate. We can see it because the topic - comment structure makes it equivalent to:

Adj + Adj + 的 + Noun

Ex: 他的高高的儿子。

"

Comment: @Puco4 Then that might be where your issue comes from. You are not aware of the difference between 他的儿子高高的 and 他的高高的儿子. 他的高高的儿子 means "the son of his who is very tall" and 他的儿子高高的 "his son is very tall". They are very distinctive indeed.

Comment: Well, my main question was *where* is the verb and predicate in 他的儿子高高的. Is 高高的 working as an adjectival verb of the subject  他的儿子, even though 高高的  is the comment of the topic 他的儿子?

Comment: @Puco4 Yes, that's why I have said'高高的 is acting the same as 很高 grammatically.

Comment: @Puco4 If this could help you, you can add a 的 at the end of 他的儿子很高，他的儿子很高的.  Maybe, this way you might be able to better align with Adj + Adj + 的.  If this would add more confusion, then you can just forget it.  haha.

Comment: I would vote to delete this post. It just asked the same as my other post but was mixed with all my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reflection, I believe **the underlying grammar** of the *topic - comment* `Noun - Adj + 的` sentence is:

> `Noun - (是) + Adj + 的`
>
> Noun - (is) an Adj one.

**So the verb `是` is omitted, the predicate is `(是) + Adj + 的` and the subject is `Noun`.** This is because `Adj + 的` *nominalizes* the `Adj`, and we still need a verb. (If anyone can provide an alternative explanation, I would be interested to hear it).

In the example:

> 他的儿子 - 高的。
>
> His son - (is) a tall one.

---

There are two *alternative* ways to express it:

1. **Explicitly with 是**:

   > 他的儿子 是 高的。
   >
   > His son *is* a tall one.

   Although this introduces some emphasis on the adjective ([@dan, @blackgreen](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/40001/25265)).
2. **`Noun + (Adv of degree) + Adj` structure**:

   > 他的儿子很高。
   >
   > His son is tall.

---

A *different grammatical* expression is the **noun phrase `Adj + 的 + Noun`** (@fefe, @dan):

> 他的高的儿子。
>
> His tall son.

---

**A reduplication of adjectives `Adj + Adj` is still an `Adj`**, so all the previous grammatical considerations hold.

However, as pointed by [@dan](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/40002/25265), a reduplication of the adjective has a different semantic meaning: the adjective becomes more *vivid, cutie, lively, etc.*

Comment: 他的儿子 - 高的。 is a stilted sentence. 他的儿子很高。is idiomatic.

Comment: Maybe writing 他的儿子 - 很高的 looks better?

Comment: Stilted means incorrect though? Because maybe it is not the most used expression but could be useful for the explanation (if you can think of some better example).

Comment: Yeah, 他的儿子很高(的) is common.

Answer (score 1):

> *How “Noun + Adj + Adj + 的” (reduplication of adjectives) is grammatically equivalent to “Noun + (Adv of degree) + Adj”?*

[Noun + Adj X2 + 的] = [Noun + degree adv + adj]

- Both are 'topic-comment' sentence
- [Adj X2 + 的] functions the same as [degree adv + adj] in this case (a noun at the beginning but no noun at the end)

Answer (score 1):

Really strange that as a Chinese I found this grammer never met before. Please forget your "nonce + adj + adj" form. This is just an eliptical sentence.

To make this simple, you should know a `basic sentence` structure:

`主语`(subject) + `谓语`(predicate) + `宾语` (object)

so:

- `他的儿子高高的`:    `他的儿子`(主)  + (省略了 `是` 这个谓语) +  `高高的` (宾语)
- equivalent Chinese:  His son `is` very tall.

and:

- `小猫白白的`:       `小猫`(主)  + (省略了 `是` 这个谓语) + `白白的` (宾语)
- equivalent English: The cat `is` white.

Comment: So indeed 是 is omitted, thanks!

Comment: Could you write this answer here https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39997/25265 ? I think I will just delete this post as it practically asks the same as the other post

Comment: OK, posted.  you can delete this thread.

Comment: @Puco4 Just so you know, this answer is not right.

Comment: Why not right?  give me your reason.  I don't as a Chinese my answer is not right .